# Multiple default gateways on Windows

Tags: windows-10, networking, vpn, gateway, udp

I have a custom made imaging instrument to which I connect using ethernet cable and to make it work I have to set static IP and gateway on my laptop's network interface connected to the device. Communication goes over UDP.

Now to the problem. To use VPN I also have to change the gateway. This time on the wifi network interface.

When I do that Windows shows me a message about multiple gateways being in use. I'm not sure to which extent that is a problem. However sometimes VPN don't seem to work.

1. Is it a problem to have multiple gateways?
2. Is the gateway "universal" for my host or each network interface can have a different gateway?

This actually is a Parallels virtual machine however I got same results running it directly on hardware (not in a vm).

The `route print -4` returns:

```
===========================================================================
    Interface List
     12...00 1c 42 27 1c 2c ......Intel(R) 82574L Gigabit Network Connection
      1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
    ===========================================================================
    
    IPv4 Route Table
    ===========================================================================
    Active Routes:
    Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
              0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      10.211.55.1     10.211.55.15     25
          10.211.55.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      10.211.55.15    281
         10.211.55.15  255.255.255.255         On-link      10.211.55.15    281
        10.211.55.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      10.211.55.15    281
            127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
            127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
      127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
            224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
            224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      10.211.55.15    281
      255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
      255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      10.211.55.15    281
    ===========================================================================
    Persistent Routes:
      Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
              0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.2      90
              0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.2      90
              0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     192.168.11.2      90
    ===========================================================================
```

I'm wondering about the reason for the two identical lines in the end:

```
     0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.2      90
      0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.2      90
```

Comment: You might be able to trick out your routing table to handle this.  Try the command `route print -4` to see what is going on.

Comment: Added the output to the question

Answer (score 1):

> I have a custom made imaging instrument to which I connect using ethernet cable and to make it work I have to set static IP and gateway on my laptop's network interface connected to the device.

You don't. The device is already on your local subnet, and having the correct *netmask* already gives you a route to it. (E.g. your output has a `10.211.55.0 / 255.255.255.0 / On-link` route.)

The "default gateway" is only used to reach devices *not* on the local subnet.

> Is the gateway "universal" for my host or each network interface can have a different gateway?

"Gateway" is individual to each route. I'm assuming you're actually asking about "*default* gateway", i.e. specifically about the gateways attached to those `0.0.0.0/0` routes.

In theory, each interface could have its own default gateway, *if* the OS had additional logic to select routes also by considering the *source* IP address of the packet.

But normally, as you can see in the `route` output, routes are only matched by their destination – so if you have multiple "default routes", they will be prioritized host-wide; one gateway will be used for everything (even if it would end up being the wrong choice!), others won't be used at all.

There can be exceptions:

- I *think* Windows considers the outbound interface when choosing which of multiple default routes to use. However, I haven't found any official documentation regarding to this, and haven't verified it experimentally either – only "heard about it".

  It could be that this only applies to responses for an inbound connection (i.e. an accepted socket is automatically bound to a specific interface) but not to brand new outbound connections.
- Same goes for FreeBSD. I'm sure I've heard of it supporting multi-homing and selecting the correct interface, at least for replies, but have no sources to confirm that.
- Meanwhile, Linux explicitly allows matching routes by source *and* destination – but only for IPv6, not IPv4. For example, the default v6 route on Linux is actually `::/0 from ::/0` and you could add a more specific `::/0 from 2001:db8::/48` that routes through a different gateway.
- Linux also supports "policy routing" which adds an additional layer of logic on top – there may be several routing *tables*, each with its own 0.0.0.0/0 "default route", and policy rules can decide which table to use. Setting this up is usually a little bit headache-inducing. (But it does work the same for IPv6 *and* IPv4.)

Comment: My understanding is that it is necessary to set the gateway on my laptop because communication with the device goes over udp. The device will send packets addressed to that ip (the gateway). Does this make any sense?

Comment: It *mostly* doesn't. All IP communication, whether it's UDP or TCP or something else, follows routing the same way. What are you specifying as your gateway – the device itself?

Comment: Yes, I input device ip as gateway, 192.168.1.2. I won't go as far to say the device manufacturer is doing it right but I'm assuming so.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is "sometimes VPN doesn't seem to work", you can add static route to your VPN server IP address via Wi-Fi interface.

Comment: How would I do that? By static route you mean set the gateway ip address?

Comment: for example: your VPN Server IP is 104.93.169.218 and your wifi gateway 192.158.1.2, you will add:
route add 104.93.169.218 192.168.1.2

that will make sure that traffic to VPN server going through wifi gateway, and not other gateway